# Windows 10 UWF filter exclusion on working on user Documents

Tags: windows, windows-10, uwf

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC (version 10.0.17763). I've setup everything I need and I'm configuring UWF filters. I enabled protection for `C:` volume, and added a couple of exclusion for:

- allowing write on my app folder in `C:\Program Files\CustomApp` (for updates)
- allowing write on the user's "User" Documents folder `C:\Users\User\Documents\` (custom app logs, ...)
- allowing network interfaces edit

Write on app folder (e.g. create a folder/file) and edit on network interfaces (e.g. change IP address) will persist after reboot. Write on User's Documents folder gets lost after reboot.

Am I missing something? How to have persistency on user Documents folder? Do I need to set some extra things other than the folder exclusion?

Here is the output of `uwfmgr get-config` command. Folder `C:\Users\User\Documents\` is listed in the File Exclusion, in the same way the (working) `C:\Program Files\CustomApp` folder is listed.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> uwfmgr get-config
Unified Write Filter Configuration Utility version 10.0.17763
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Current Session Settings


FILTER SETTINGS
    Filter state:    ON
    Pending commit:  N/A
    Shutdown pending:No

SERVICING SETTINGS
    Servicing State: OFF

OVERLAY SETTINGS
    Type:               RAM
    Maximum size:       1024 MB
    Warning Threshold:  512 MB
    Critical Threshold: 1024 MB
    Freespace Passthrough: OFF
    Persistent: OFF
    Reset Mode: N/A



VOLUME SETTINGS
Volume bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af [C:]
    Volume state:     Protected
    Volume ID:        bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af

    File Exclusions:
Current Session Exclusions for Volume bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af [C:]
    C:\Program Files\CustomApp
    C:\Users\User\Documents\



REGISTRY EXCLUSIONS
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi

Next Session Settings


FILTER SETTINGS
    Filter state:    ON
    Pending commit:  N/A

SERVICING SETTINGS
    Servicing State: OFF

OVERLAY SETTINGS
    Type:               RAM
    Maximum size:       1024 MB
    Warning Threshold:  512 MB
    Critical Threshold: 1024 MB
    Freespace Passthrough: OFF
    Persistent: OFF
    Reset Mode: N/A



VOLUME SETTINGS
Volume bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af [C:]
    Volume state:     Protected
    Volume ID:        bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af

    File Exclusions:
Next Session Exclusions for Volume bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af [C:]
    C:\Program Files\CustomApp
    C:\Users\User\Documents\



REGISTRY EXCLUSIONS
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi
```